# setTimeout() - Improper output in division Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout

I have created this following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kzQFQ/76/

It shows proper display when I do not select the slide manually, it automatically changes the slides on the basis of **setTimeout**. But when I select one slide out of the three slides (in the fiddle) by clicking on the below three dots it causes improper output display. I know the problem is caused because of other Timeouts which are left. I have tried using `clearTimeout` but didn't work.

Please help.

Following is the code:

```
var check=0;
var Wwidth=$(window).width()-9;

$(document).ready(function () {
$('.contentContainer').css({'width':''+Wwidth+'px'});

$('.three').click(function () {
    $('.container').animate({
        'left': '-1120px'
    });
    clearTimeout(timer);
    var timer=setTimeout(function () {$('.one').click();}, 6000);
}); 

$('.two').click(function () {
    $('.container').animate({
        'left': '-560px'
    });
    clearTimeout(timer);
    var timer=setTimeout(function () {$('.three').click();}, 6000);
});    

$('.one').click(function () {
    $('.container').animate({
        'left': ''+0+'px'
    });
    clearTimeout(timer);
    var timer=setTimeout(function () {$('.two').click();}, 6000);
});  
var timer=setTimeout(function () {$('.two').click();}, 6000);
});
```

Comment: Are you using `click` when you meant `trigger` ?

Comment: @LeeTaylor I dont understand what you are asking.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are adding click handlers inside a timeout

Comment: He can use `.click()` does't need to use `.trigger()`

Comment: @LeeTaylor if you know any better jquery way to create a slider you can post your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the variables `timer` you are using are local, so when you call clear they are `undefined`.

Add `var timer` in a global scope so that it will be a global variable and you will be able to clear timeouts then.

you can do it in the first line like this:

```
var timer;
var check=0;
var Wwidth=$(window).width()-9;
```

and remove `var` from `var timer =` in the other lines.

EDIT:

like this:

```
timer=setTimeout(function () {$('.one').click();}, 6000);
```

Comment: Ok i got it.Thanks.I was writing var timer inside also.I didnt notice it.